# How would the greek gods of the olymp kill each other?

Tags: warfare, gods, death

If two greek Gods, lets Ares and Athena, had beef and they decided to have a fight until one of them is dead, how would it be done and where would they go afterwards? What Kind of weapon could kill a god and how would death look to them? Or do they just Torture and imprison each other till the end of Time? 
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! There appears to be more than one question here. We generally ask for only one question at a time. Series of questions about a particular worldbuilding problem are common and allowed. We also don't like questions that are primarily story based as there are infinite ways that a story could go and no good criteria for determining if one answer is better than another. If you tell us how the greek gods work in your world we can give you a reason why a certain weapon works but not which weapons would work.

Comment: And please read the tag description when you use them。Strong force had nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Greek gods are immortal. As in, they don't die. Ever. For example, consider the myth of [Prometheus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prometheus), who, for having stolen fire from Olympus to give it to the mortals, was chained to a rock in the Caucasus; every day, an eagle came and ate his liver; every night, Prometheus would heal, only to be eaten alive again the next day. He was tortured in this way for a very long time, until he was freed by [Hercules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heracles). As for how gods fight, see for example the [Titanomachy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanomachy).

Comment: @AlexP Then why does Aries complain to Zeus in the *Illiad* that Diomedes almost killed him?

Comment: @ITAlex This really isn't a bunch of seperate questions; it's really just one big question. What appear to be seperate questions are just various possibilities for how to go about it.

Comment: Thank you. I am new here and little confused. Shall I reask the question, just one, and give a little insight into the idea i am trying to follow or Continue here in the Comment section?

Comment: @MarvintheParanoidAndroid: But Ares *didn't* die. And Diomedes was actually made an immortal for his valor. (Funny typo. Aries means "ram" (male sheep) in Latin, and it's the name of a zodiacal constellation.) Yes, my comment was a reductionist simplification. Greek mythology *is* luxuriant and contradictory, so that the reader can pick and choose their favorite path and sequence of events. (Ah, and BTW, about *"what weapons":* Athena has standard military attributes: her helmet, her shield and her spear. It would be strange if she fought with other weapons. But she is occasionally flexible.)

Comment: I am Not a specialist in greek mythology looking for a loophole in eternity. The idea is a little bit what Shakespeare did in a  midsummernights dream. Oberon and Titania are king and queen of the fairy Kingdom, with Magical powers, but they behave like humans in their quarrel. So i thought it might be interesting to explore the world og the greek gods: what would they feel if they had to face some Kind of end to their immortality.

Comment: just create your own godly weapon enhanced or made by Hephaestus, he manage to create chain net that trap gods, i dont think he has trouble to create god slayer weaponry.

Comment: @MarvintheParanoidAndroid How would they kill each other, Where would they go, and what weapon could do it, all seem like very distinct questions to me.

Answer (score 1):

**How could it be done?**

Greek mythology contains a million variations of each story. They were never "properly immortal". For every story where Athena springs from the busted head of Zeus but he gets better, or Prometheus regrows his wounds every day, there is another where Saturn devours his children, or kills his father and reforges his body into the sky.

The Greek gods were not immune to mortal weapons. In Book 5 of the Illiad (Ian Johnston) the mortal Diomedes (guided by Athena) wounds Ares with his spear.

> Diomedes, skilled in war cries, then made the second thrust with his bronze spear. Pallas Athena guided the weapon right to Ares’ gut,  the lower part where his waist band went around him. Diomedes wounded Ares, piercing his fair skin, then pulled back on his spear. Brazen Ares roared as loud as the screams of nine or ten thousand men when they clash in war.

On the other hand there are many creatures in the Mythology that are vulnerable to weapons but seem unkillable. For example the Titan Typhon is buried under mount Etna, still alive, which causes the eruptions, and there are versions of Hercules where the hydra's last head was unkillable so he buried it under a rock.

**What would death look like to them?**

It is called the Greek underworld. The main difference in most mythology is that $-$ for the gods at least $-$ the land of the dead is not another state of being, but is a physical place they can visit and attempt to bust their loved ones out of by force.

Is there much of a difference between being buried under a mountain and trapped in the underworld? If the underworld is a physical place you can travel to by digging then I'd wager not.

Some mortals even walked into the underworld. In the Aeneid there is an entrance near Lake Avernus in Italy.  For Aeneas the main barrier is the river Styx, where he only gets across because Charon recognises his demigod status.

Sometimes there are other guardians like Cerberus, who are too big and strong for a mortal to get into the underworld. Though Orpheus did it once by putting the dogs to sleep with his lyre. . . .

I would presume gods getting back and forth is largely a matter of tedious paperwork, which could be delayed hundreds or thousands of years if someone wanted to keep you out.

In my imagination there are two broad categories for "death of a god"

1. They are physically overpowered, chopped up et cetera. Before their wounds are healed (all gods do this over time) they are thrown in the underworld. They eventually get better but cannot escape.
2. They are physically overpowered but then de-personified. They are still alive but become passive nature gods, like Gaia or Uranus $-$ or even Tartarus himself, who is sometimes treated as a god rather than a location.

The primary example of both are the Titans, who were defeated by the Olympians [many eons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRq7lLawQB4) ago. Presumably the Olympians follow similar rules.

Comment: Thank you. I am Not a specialist in greek mythology looking for a loophole in eternity. The idea is a little bit what Shakespeare did in a midsummernights dream. Oberon and Titania are king and queen of the fairy Kingdom, with Magical powers, but they behave like humans in their quarrel. So i thought it might be interesting to explore the world og the greek gods: what would they feel if they had to face some Kind of end to their immortality. –

Comment: Cronus did devour his children, but they were eventually disgorged -- they are the third generation gods who rule the world in the bulk of Greek mythology. (And the Roman Saturnus devoured his children only in his later hypostasis as the Roman counterpart of Cronus. The original Italic Saturnus did no such thing.)

Comment: @Sindata: You can become an expert fairly quickly by reading some primary sources. The number of surviving primary sources is much smaller than the number of modern interpretations!

Comment: @Sindata: The Greek gods totally behave like (childish) humans in their quarrels. The whole Troy debacle began over an argument over which of Athena, Hera, and Aphrodite was more beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

This has been addressed a lot of ways in various stories. You should feel free to take liberties with your final choice.

- I personally like the idea that the gods are immortal due to ambrosia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambrosia and they retain their powers due to it. Place a god in a situation where they are trapped away from it and they are helpless. However, even when a god's influence waxes and wanes, they never seem to go completely away. My interpretation is that the gods can't completely die, but they are clever and when they want to do each other in they make some special arrangement that somehow entraps them. You'll notice this doesn't happen much except at the command of the head of the gods (so everyone agrees). The gods almost never directly contest with each other, and when they do the fabric of the world is seriously altered. Mostly there's a lot of fleeing and hiding, and eventually something breaks the situation - an appeal to Zeus, a neutral ally intervening, etc. Athena is awfully clever, and I wouldn't put odds on poor Ares in a contest like this.
- In more modern interpretations of Greek mythology, The gods can (and often have) died. Here, the interpretation is not so kind. The gods are often portrayed as not having a soul, so if they are killed they are destroyed forever and cannot return. The means of killing them generally end up being the doom of all the gods and their entire system. Here Ares would have a definite advantage - it's usually something everyone knows about but no one dares use (like the blood of the golden Hind). Ares is the god most often portrayed killing all the others (Think the Hercules Tv show w. Kevin Sorbo or the movie Wonder Woman)
- Other interpretations say a god fades if people stop worshipping an believing in them. The gods were frequently portrayed as being obsessed with their temples and worshippers. Smash their temples and kill their followers and they become no more than myth and legend, perhaps pale imitations of their former selves. If you could erase them from history, they would disappear.

Comment: the first one sounds like the reason for tartarus

Comment: @DW/Kraus Thank you.